# Converting XML configuration to java configuration in spring security for global method security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to convert **xml configuration to java config**

My XML configuration like this

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="methodAccessDecisionManager">
        <security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>
```

I am tried to convert with annotation

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
```

But I am not getting how I can convert and use with global security method `access-decision-manager-ref="methodAccessDecisionManager"`
and `<security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom method security configruation, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#globalmethodsecurityconfiguration):

> **5.10.2 GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration**
>
> Sometimes you may need to perform operations that are more complicated than are possible with the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation allow. For these instances, you can extend the `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` ensuring that the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation is present on your subclass. For example, if you wanted to provide a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, you could use the following configuration:
>
> ```java
> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
> public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
>   @Override
>   protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
>       // ... create and return custom MethodSecurityExpressionHandler ...
>       return expressionHandler;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> For additional information about methods that can be overridden, refer to the `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` Javadoc.

Your modified code:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Autowired
    private MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler;

    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }
}
```